# using localStorage within a for in loop

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage, for-in-loop

This is my first post on stackOverflow although I have been lingering around the forums when I have needed help.
However, I was unable to find an answer for my current problem so thought it was best I made an account and asked.

It is a workout application with 3 pages - page 1: user selects what gym equipment (bike, rower or x trainer) they wish to use and what difficulty, page 2: All workouts available specific to the options selected. page 3: the actual workout to complete.

Basically, I am trying (if possible), to store certain data in a localStorage object depending on what link the user clicks on, but what keeps happening is the last value in the *for in* loop keeps storing no matter which link is clicked. Please see below and hopefully you can see what I mean:

PAGE 1: (there are 2 dropdown menus, the first the user selects what equipment they wish to use, and the second option they choose the difficulty of the workout):

```
//constructor function - create workouts with instances of this function
function Workout(name, desc, loc, work_rest, res, intensity){
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.loc = loc;
    this.work_rest = work_rest;
    this.res = res;
    this.intensity = intensity;
}


//CREATE WORKOUTS
var bike = {
    easy: [
        {workout_1: new Workout('Tabata', 'This is a tabata style workout', '../Workout_page_example/index.html', [20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10], [8,2,8,2,8,2,8,2,8,2,8,2,8,2,8,2], [120,60,120,60,120,60,120,60,120,60,120,60,120,60,120,60])},
        {workout_2: new Workout('Classic_HIIT', 'This is a HIIT session', '../Workout_page_example/index.html',[60,30,60,30],[7,3,7,3],[100, 70, 100, 70])},
        {workout_3: new Workout('Clock_Face', 'Beat the clock', '../Workout_page_example/index.html',[120, 60, 110, 60, 100, 60], [7,4,7,4,7,4],[120, 60, 120, 60, 120, 60])}
    ],
    int:[

    ],
    adv:[

    ]
};

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //dependant on options - send storage information to 'choose a workout page'

    if(equipment.value === "bike"){

        if(difficulty.value === "easy"){
            localStorage.setItem('get_info', JSON.stringify(bike.easy));
        }else if(difficulty.value === "int"){
            localStorage.setItem('get_info', JSON.stringify(bike.int));
        }else if(difficulty.value === "adv"){
            localStorage.setItem('get_info', JSON.stringify(bike.adv));
        }
}

    //send storage information for specific workout to this page
    location.href = 'workouts/index.html';
})
```

so this above page is fine - Sorry if it appears a bit blocky, I only showed the relevant parts as it is a fairly big script, hopefully you can figure out what each variable is in relation to the DOM as they are pretty straight forward.
So the problem appears on page 2, this page displays all the workouts available for the equipment and difficulty selected by the user, which is as follows:

PAGE 2: (This page displays all workouts of the equipment and difficulty selected)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var getInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('get_info'));
    var dom = document.getElementById('section');



    for(var key in getInfo){
        var obj = getInfo[key];

        for(var prop in obj){


            dom.innerHTML += "<hr/><div class ='workout_title'> <h1>"+obj[prop].name.replace('_',' ')+"</h1></div>"; //replace underscore with space in workout names with more than one word - display name
            dom.innerHTML += "<div class='workout_desc'><h4>"+obj[prop].desc+"</h4></div>"; //display description


            localStorage.setItem('work_rest', JSON.stringify(obj[prop].work_rest));
            localStorage.setItem('resistance', JSON.stringify(obj[prop].res));
            localStorage.setItem('intensity', JSON.stringify(obj[prop].intensity));

            dom.innerHTML += "<div class='workout_link'><a href='"+ obj[prop].loc +"' id='"+obj[prop].name+"'>START >></a></div>";

        }

    }

})
```

When the user clicks on one of the links - the localStorage obj only stores the last of the object instances passed in. So in this example the data for the instance with the name 'clock_face'. I can understand why it is happening, but I am unsure as to how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through your 3 workouts and storing the values without even waiting for the user to select the workout, so of course you're overwriting the stored workout on every iteration and therefore only the last course in the array is actually stored (having overwritten the previous one, which in turn overwrote the previous one, which...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any idea how I can correct this? I have messed around with conditionals in and outside the loop and I still can not get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    var getInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('get_info'));
    var dom = document.getElementById('section');

    var names=[]; //initiate names array
    var workRestArr = [];
    var resArr = [];
    var intArr = [];


    for(var key in getInfo){
        var obj = getInfo[key];


        for(var prop in obj){

            dom.innerHTML += "<hr/><div class ='workout_title'> <h1>"+obj[prop].name.replace('_',' ')+"</h1></div>"; //replace underscore with space in workout names with more than one word - display name
            dom.innerHTML += "<div class='workout_desc'><h4>"+obj[prop].desc+"</h4></div>"; //display description

            dom.innerHTML += "<div class='workout_link'><a id='"+obj[prop].name+"'>START >></a></div>";


            names.push(obj[prop].name); //store all ids in names array
            workRestArr.push(obj[prop].work_rest); //store all work_rest in array
            resArr.push(obj[prop].res); // store all resistance levels in array
            intArr.push(obj[prop].intensity); //store all intensity levels in an array

        }

    }


    for(var i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
        var el = document.getElementById(names[i]);
        var w = workRestArr[i];
        var r = resArr[i];
        var int = intArr[i];

        (function(w, r, int) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                localStorage.setItem('work_rest', JSON.stringify(w));
                localStorage.setItem('resistance', JSON.stringify(r));
                localStorage.setItem('intensity', JSON.stringify(int));
                location.href = '../Workout_Page_example/index.html';
            })
        })(w, r, int);

    }

})
```

Although I am still not sure how this works exactly, I imagine its due to closures and scope of the variables but it would help to have this explained in more detail. Thanks